# Tkinter frame tkraise Entry bug

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a multiple window GUI and I found a video (https://youtu.be/jBUpjijYtCk) that shows the functionality of tk raise with multiple frames. However I'm facing a bug when I press the button "Visit Page 1" all labels and even "ADICIONAR" button dissapears, but not the Entries, what should I do for it to work properly?

The code I'm writing about happens on the StartPage class.

The Client class isn't important, its just a class I created to store data.

```
from tkinter import *
from client import Client
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 16)
MEDIUM_FONT = ("VERDANA", 12)

clients = []

class Sea(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        self.geometry("800x500")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = Label(self, text="Adicionar cliente", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.place(x=50, y=100)

        label = Label(self, text="Nome", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label.place(x=10, y=160)
        self.name_entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.name_entry.place(x=100, y=162)

        label = Label(self, text="GSM", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label.place(x=10, y=200)
        self.gsm_entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.gsm_entry.place(x=100, y=202)

        label = Label(self, text="Email", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label.place(x=10, y=240)
        self.email_entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.email_entry.place(x=100, y=242)

        label = Label(self, text="Local", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label.place(x=10, y=280)
        self.local_entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.local_entry.place(x=100, y=282)

        label = Label(self, text="Produto", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label.place(x=10, y=320)
        self.product_entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.product_entry.place(x=100, y=322)

        add_button = Button(self, text="ADICIONAR", command=self.adicionar)
        add_button.place(x=100, y=360)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Visit Page 1", 
                        command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        self.button.place(x=500, y=20)

    def adicionar(self):
        if(self.name_entry.get()=="" or self.gsm_entry.get()=="" or self.local_entry.get()=="" or self.product_entry.get()==""):
            return

        clients.append(Client(self.name_entry.get(), self.gsm_entry.get(), self.local_entry.get(), self.gsm_entry.get()))
        print(clients)

class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = Button(self, text="Start Page", 
                        command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

app = Sea()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pass the `Frame` instance to your `Entry` classes, so you're not putting them into your frame. Pass the `self` parameter to each of your `Entry` instance and it will work:

```
self.name_entry = Entry(self, width=30)
```

Do that for all entries.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Entry` widget are not created as child of your StartPage Frame. So simply add `(self,...)` at the beginning of each Entry command